# COGNITO OIDC Signout of IDP -OKTA

Tags: amazon-cognito, okta

Configured OKTA as OIDC Identity Provider in my cognito user pool.  In Okta App Admin provided the below
as Sign in URL https://.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse

What do I provide the Signout Url in OKTA.  Tried the below its not working
https://.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com/Logout

Tried to signout from Cognito Hosted UI the below way but its not signing the user out of OKTA

https://<pooldomain name.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&logout_uri=https://www.example.com/logout

Comment: can anyone assist me on this one

Answer (score 0):

This is a top result in Google, but there's no answer provided yet. I did some troubleshooting on my side, and when I used the Audience URI (SP Entity ID) value as the SP Issuer value, logouts work.

So in Okta,

1. Select Applications.
2. Select your application (the one you created and linked with Cognito. More details in the link below)
3. Click General
4. Under SAML Settings, click Edit
5. On the general settings tab, click Next
6. On the SAML Settings tab, click Show Advanced Settings
7. Copy your value for Audience URI (SP Entity ID)
8. Check the box for: Enable Single Logout
9. For Single Logout URL, use: https://<YOUR_DOMAIN>.auth..amazoncognito.com/saml2/logout
10. For SP Issuer, paste the value you copied from step #7
11. For Signature Certificate, upload the Cognito cert for your pool.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-okta-saml-identity-provider/

Comment: bro, the question was addressed for OIDC, not SAML

Comment: Wow, yep. You’re totally right! Sorry about that. At the time, I remember digging and digging and not finding an answer anywhere. Looks like in my haste, I answered the wrong question. Please ignore this..

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/)

But what you you're interested in is:

```
https://server.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

There you should find `end_session_endpoint`